# Free grayscale images dataset with ground truth to pre-train U-Net used later into brain mri segmentation

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, images

I'm looking for a free image dataset to test my U-Net network.

I'm developing a brain mri segmentation algorithm and I need data to train it. This algorithm will segmentate brain tumors and I need a dataset with brain images and ground truth images.

Do you know if there is any dataset like the one I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Multimodal Brain Tumor Segmentation Challenge 2019](https://www.med.upenn.edu/cbica/brats2019/data.html)

Imaging Data Description
All BraTS multimodal scans are available as NIfTI files (.nii.gz) and describe a) native (T1) and b) post-contrast T1-weighted (T1Gd), c) T2-weighted (T2), and d) T2 Fluid Attenuated Inversion Recovery (T2-FLAIR) volumes, and were acquired with different clinical protocols and various scanners from multiple (n=19) institutions, mentioned as data contributors here.

All the imaging datasets have been segmented manually, by one to four raters, following the same annotation protocol, and their annotations were approved by experienced neuro-radiologists. Annotations comprise the GD-enhancing tumor (ET — label 4), the peritumoral edema (ED — label 2), and the necrotic and non-enhancing tumor core (NCR/NET — label 1), as described both in the BraTS 2012-2013 TMI paper and in the latest BraTS summarizing paper (also see Fig.1). The provided data are distributed after their pre-processing, i.e. co-registered to the same anatomical template, interpolated to the same resolution (1 mm^3) and skull-stripped.

---

[BRATS 2015: Brain Tumor Image Segmentation Challenge](https://www.smir.ch/BRATS/Start2015)

---

[LGG Segmentation Dataset](http://kaggle.com/mateuszbuda/lgg-mri-segmentation?)

This dataset contains brain MR images together with manual FLAIR abnormality segmentation masks.
The images were obtained from The Cancer Imaging Archive (TCIA).
They correspond to 110 patients included in The Cancer Genome Atlas (TCGA) lower-grade glioma collection with at least fluid-attenuated inversion recovery (FLAIR) sequence and genomic cluster data available.
Tumor genomic clusters and patient data is provided in data.csv file.

---

Additional Resources for Deep Learning/AI image processing

- http://www.imageprocessingplace.com/root_files_V3/image_databases.htm

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helps me a lot. I have a question about LGG Segmentation Dataset: Are these brain images greyscale? Because when I open it in Windows Explorer or with Gimp, I see a lot of colours. And Image Properties in Gimp show this: "Color space: RGB Color".